Linearized formulas and constraints
I am researching how to linearize the maximum and minimum functions in optimization problems and have encountered some confusion.

I am linearizing an equation, and the max
equation( upper ) and $\mbox{min equation( lower )}$ in the figure are equivalent.
However, after linearization, their constraints are the
same, but the final form does not appear to be equivalent ( notes here ) such as
$$
\beta_{1}s^{+} + \beta_{2}s^{-}
\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\beta_{1}s^{+} - \beta_{2}s^{-}
$$

I think they are not equivalent.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

hmmm..... what do you mean "starting with two original formulas"? I think you're saying you applied this process to two functions.... Why not write down these functions for us?

It's pretty hard to understand what you are asking. I'm going to try to edit your post so you don't get down-voted out. I might get your question incorrect, though.

I don't know, it's pretty difficult to understand what you've written here. Try this:
"I am researching how to linearize the maximum and minimum functions in optimization problems and have encountered some confusion.
Let $f_1=\cdots$ and $f_2=\cdots$. I tried linearizing them by introducing auxiliary variables $s+$ and $s-$ (notes here) and got $\cdots$. I'm assuming I have made some error handling the positive and negative signs here."
The sentence after that makes no sense whatsoever.

Looks like a sign error in the final line.  If
$$y = \beta_{1}\max\{x,0\} - \beta_{2}\min\{x,0\},$$
$$s^+ = \max\{x,0\},$$
and
$$s^- = -\min\{x,0\},$$
then
$$y = \beta_{1}\max\{x,0\} + \beta_{2}(-\min\{x,0\}) = \beta_{1}s^+ + \beta_{2}s^-.$$
